# Specifying GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS for a cocoapod from Podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using [MTDates](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates) library for some date calculations in my app. And of course it's added to my project as a [cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org).

MTDates adds methods like `mt_startOfCurrentHour` to `NSDate`. But also it has an option to use method names without `mt_` prefix. Just `startOfCurrentHour`. For enabling it we need to define a preprocessor macross `MTDATES_NO_PREFIX=1`.

In podscpec file it can be achieved with:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => 'MTDATES_NO_PREFIX=1' }
```

But in [the released podscpec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/87f06c53cd6163eda4793181975982199267aaf2) there is no such line. So short method names are not enabled by default.

I'd like to use short method names and to add MTDates as a cocoapod to my project.

Currently I've came with copying podspec to project repo, adding that line and point to custom podspec from Podfile:

```
pod 'MTDates', :podspec => 'config/MTDates.podspec'
```

**How can I specify a preprocessor macros for a pod in Podfile without completely overriding a podspec?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this by using the Podfile’s [`post_install` hook](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#post_install) to modify the `Pods.xcodeproj` after installation. The example basically shows you all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks! After spending some time I've came with this solution https://gist.github.com/yas375/fef76f737ca88c661311 But some weird thing is happening. It adds `MTDATES_NO_PREFIX=1` for Debug configuration for all targets in Pods project. Not sure if it's correct... I'm almost prepared a test project to demonstrate it...

Comment: Here are my explanations on what I meant: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1322 ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will link to this in the README for those who are curious, but my answer to this question is to strongly suggest using the prefix. Third party libraries *really* need to add a prefix to their category methods, especially when distributing to the public via something like cocoapods or…there is no other acceptable way.

I hope to one day be able to yank the non-prefixed methods out of MTDates so just consider it :)

Comment: Adding some info about this to the README sounds very good to me! :) It definitely should be useful for other developers.